# How to execute Python or Go script in sandbox without access to internet?

Tags: security, sandbox, brute-force

The goal is to run a brute-force script of Python or Go that was taken from GitHub in order to perform brute-force on the cryptocurrency wallet. (All legal helping out  a customer)

I don't want to write my own script but prefer reusing the existing scripts I found. The risk is that the existing scripts might have functionality that will transfer the content of the wallet to another account in case of success and in case if the amount is more then the certain threshold. If its well hidden it might be not 100% safe to just trace the code.

Other than running the machine offline what are my best options to mitigate this potential risk?

Comment: Use docker, by closing all ports or append a script which disables internet whenever you run the following program.

Comment: Which operating system will you be running the script on?

Comment: Why don't you want to write your own scripts?  You might trust them better than outside ones...

Comment: I will be using windows OS.